# address of local variable

Tags: c++

I have a hard time understanding the difference between these three:

```
const char * f() {
  return "this is a test";
}

const char * g() {
  const char * str = "test again";
  return str;
}

const double * h() {
  const double a = 2.718;
  return &a;
}
```

I get a warning for the `h()`, as `warning: address of local variable ‘a’ returned`. Which makes sense, but I do not understand why the compiler (`gcc -Wall`) is ok with the `f()` and `g()` function.

- Isn't there a local variable there?
- When and how does the pointer returned by `f()` or `g()` gets deallocated?

Comment: Those string literals *aren't* locals.

Comment: You're returning constant strings, they are allocated statically in the executable and wont be allocated and deallocated at runtime.

Comment: as you have not allocated memory to f() and g(), so they are not deallocated, they are just overwritten

Comment: They don't get deallocated, either. Bad Things can happen when you try to dealloc string literals (they're often baked into the executable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String literals are not stored in the local stack frame.  They live in a fixed place in your executable.  Contrast:

```
const char * g() {
  const char * p = "test again";
  return p;
}
```

with

```
const char * g() {
  const char a[] = "test again";
  return a;
}
```

In the former, the return value points to a fixed place in your executable.  In the latter, the return value points to (a now invalid location in) the stack.

Answer (score 6):

It's string literals.

n3337 2.14.5/8

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow
> string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has
> **static storage duration**

Answer (score 3):

```
const char * g() {
  const char * str = "test again";
  return str;
}
```

This doesn't return the address of local variable. The variable is `str`, and **therefore** it address should be `&str` which would be **different** from `str` itself:

```
std::cout << (void*) str  << std::endl; 
std::cout << (void*) &str << std::endl; //address of str (local variable)
```

They would print **different** values!

So a more apt example would be this:

```
const char ** g() {
  const char * str = "test again";
  return &str;  //difference!
}
```

Now it returns the address of the local variable. A good compiler *may* issue warning for this.

Another example would be this:

```
const char * g() {
  const char str[] = "test again"; //difference!
  return str;  //same as before
}
```

Now even though you return `str` which doesn't *seem* to be the address of the local variable, it may give warning, as in this case, the value of `str` and `&str` would be exactly same! Try printing these now:

```
std::cout << (void*) str  << std::endl; 
std::cout << (void*) &str << std::endl; //address of str (local variable)
```

They would print the **same** value!

Comment: You cannot return `&str`, because its type `const char(*)[11]` is incompatible with the return type `const char*`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: What? It is `const char**` when I use `&str`, then `const char**` is perfectly fine!

Comment: What version of the function are you talking about `g`? :) I was referring to the last version where `str` is an array.

Comment: @FredOverflow: In the last version, I don't return `&str`.

Comment: But you said "in this case, the value of `str` and `&str` would be exactly same". However, If I replace `return str;` with `return &str;`, g++ complains "Fehler: »`const char (*)[11]`« kann nicht nach »`const char*`« in Rückgabe umgewandelt werden".

Comment: @FredOverflow: the *value* would be same, not the *type*. There is a difference, don't you think so?

Answer (score 1):

In the function `h`, `a` is a local variable that won't exist after the function returns. You're returning a *pointer* to that variable, and so dereferencing the pointer outside the function is incorrect, and undefined behavior.

In `f` and `g` you're returning literal strings. Literal strings have static storage: they *aren't* allocated on the stack, and they'll exist beyond the lifetime of the functions.

In the definition of `g`:

```
const char *g()
{
   const char *str = "test again";
   return str;
}
```

`str` *is* a local variable, but it's a pointer to *non*-local - statically allocated - memory. It's that address that you're returning, not a reference to the local variable.

Consider another definition of `g`:

```
const char *g()
{
    const char str[] = "test again";
    // incorrect: can't use str after the return:
    return str;
}
```

Now `g` has the same problem as your function `h`, and when compiling it you should see the same warning about returning the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The string literals aren't local variables. The string equivalent of the third function is this

```
const char * f() {
  const char str[] = "this is a test";
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storage allocation for string literals is static, that is why you don't get a warning.

Try this and you will get undefined behavior:

```
const char* getFoo()
{

  std::string foo("hi");
  return foo.c_str();
}
```

Because the string foo made a copy of the literal string.

Answer (score 0):

These strings are physically and permanently placed inside your data memeory, so their addresses are permanent. The automatic variable is on the stack, so it will disappear the moment you return from the call.